I can't run odoo on nginx using docker
I am trying to run odoo on nginx in docker but the page is giving me an error.
my docker compose
(https://i.sstatic.net/19Z6aEW3.png)
my configuration ngix
(https://i.sstatic.net/jt5bGLPF.png)
web error
(https://i.sstatic.net/wicVvG3Y.png)
I want to run odoo on nginx to apply the advantages that this has. If someone could help me I would be very grateful for it.

Shouldn't you call http://localhost/web?

 docker-compose.yml (Simplified version without some volume mounts.)
version: '3.1'
services:
  odoo_v2:
    image: odoo:17
    depends_on:
      - db_v2
    environment:
      - HOST=db_v2
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
    ports:
      - 8069:8069

  db_v2:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - odoo_v2

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:

 nginx/default.conf
upstream odoo {
    server odoo_v2:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
    server odoo_v2:8072;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect http://odoo/ http://$host/;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;
}

Go to http://localhost/.

